# Generational GC source code

Tags: c, compiler-construction, resources, garbage-collection

I am studying GC implementations, and I'm currently looking for references and good open-source GC examples to base in.

Is there any good and simple generational GC implementation ? The second best thing would be good resources and guidelines!

Thank you!

Comment: @Waneck: out of curiosity, what kind of GC do you want, and what kind of software motivates your question? (if it is a compiler, for what language or kind of language?)

Comment: I'm currently finishing the HaXe (http://haxe.org) targets for C# and Java, and I intend to apply everything I learned from optimizing dynamic accesses to an ANSI C target. I was looking for generational GC's because haxe borrows much from funcional programming, and I really wanted to be able to have mainly short lived objects.

Comment: But after having a look right now at the alternatives,  I still have doubts over which path to follow, since my primary two applications would benefit very much from soft real-time and multi-threading: games and servers. I'm having a look right now at java's G1 architecture, but at first I'm probably going to implement something in the likes of Qish. I didn't feel too comfortable with volatiles everywhere, but I guess it's a fair requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've wrote the [Qish](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/qishintro.html) garbage collector (not really maintained any more, but feel free to ask). It is a free copying generational GC for C (with some coding styles restrictions).

The GCC [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) [meta-]plugin (free, GPLv3 licensed), providing a high level language, MELT, to extend the GCC compiler, also has a copying generational GC above the existing `Ggc` garbage collector of GCC. Look into [gcc/melt-runtime.c](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/branches/melt-branch/gcc/melt-runtime.c)

With generational copying GC, generating the application's code in C is quite useful. See [my DSL2011 paper on MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/MELT-Starynkevitch-DSL2011.pdf)

Feel free to ask me more, I love talking about my GC-s.

Of course, reading the [Garbage Collection Handbook: The Art of Automatic Memory Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420082795)  (Jones, Hosking, Moss)  [ISBN-13: 978-1420082791] is a must

---

<sup>(added in 2017)</sup>

Look also into [Ravenbrook's Memory Pool System](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps) which can be used for generational GC.

Look also into the runtime of [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/), which has a good (single-threaded) generational GC.

---

PS. Debugging a generational copying GC is painful.

Comment: Qish looks pretty cool, though I wish you finished multithreading too (I imagine it doesn't play well with explicit `qish_write_notify()` though). If I remember, I might port this to Windows at some point...

Comment: multi-threading GC is difficult, and multi-threading generational GC is even more difficult. I've read perhaps a thousand papers on GC without having a good idea of how to do a good multi-threaded generational GC.

Comment: Oh I don't doubt, it wasn't a request - literally a wish in this case :). If you could run a GC instance per-thread, it would probably be fine for a lot of cases since you're already requiring a lot of the user, and object references crossing threads is a Bad Idea in general. (though you might need more robust object rooting?)

Comment: wow, I really really liked your code. And it's really what I've been looking for, since I'm generating c code from a compiler. Thanks!
Just bought the book, by the way

Comment: It would be great, though, to have it implemented really for concurrent access. Though maybe as you've said, a generational gc might not be the best option for concurrency. Anyway your code gives me a good start! Thanks

Comment: Look also at my MELT GC and my DSL11 paper; it is for generated code... Some people told me about Qish that it is using not very portable tricks (I forgot which, perhaps va_arg related)..

Comment: I will look at them too, thank you very much! I'd love to talk better about the gc design, if you want I can post my findings here or we can get in touch by mail (don't know SO's policy on comments flood :) )?

Comment: As you want; my email is publicly available.

Answer (score 5):

#### Java's HotSpot GC

You can look at the various GC implementations provided by the JVM [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/modules/hotspot/file/9646293b9637/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/).

The [Memory Management white paper](http://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/whitepapers/memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf) gives an overview of the different garbage collectors implemented in the JVM. Its from 2006 so its missing the new G1 collector details but its a good starting point.

#### Mon's SGen GC

Mono's new [SGen](http://mono-project.com/Generational_GC) is on [github](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/e4b9b8802066f6ed8cca151fe8cddcb4f3262806/mono/metadata) too. Check out the sgen files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it seems very complex to be able to get the gist of it... Maybe when I'm more versed into the algorithms it will be a great resource!

Answer (score 4):

The [Ovm framework](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jv/soft/ovm/s.html) is open source and offers a framework that allows to select several features regarding garbage collection for real-time systems.

According to the website

> Includes Minuteman RTGC framework which allows to select from newly
>   supported RTGC features: time-based scheduling (periodic, slack, and
>   hybrid - a combination of both), incremental stack scanning,
>   replication or Brooks barrier, incremental object copy, arraylets,
>   memory usage, and GC pause profiling and tracing.

Although domain specific, it may be a good starting point for your study.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The [V8 project](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) (Javascript engine used in Chrome and Android) is open source and has a simple generational garbage collector.

You can [browse the source code online](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc). In particular, look at heap.cc (implementation of the heap and scavenge algorithm), spaces.cc (lower level heap stuff), and mark-compact.cc (full garbage collector).

Answer (score 3):

The Parrot VM also uses a [generational garbage collector](https://github.com/parrot/parrot/blob/master/src/gc/gc_gms.c).

Comment: +1 ! Really one of the cleanest implementations ! Thanks for the link! If only the 'big' vm's could comment their code like this!

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not in written in C, the [JikesRVM](http://jikesrvm.org/) JVM contains several GC implementations, including a  couple of generational ones, and I think it's rather simple to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The [Boehm Garbage Collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) is commonly used for C and C++ projects.

Comment: The Boehm-GC does not use generational garbage collection.

Comment: @silentbicycle: [The collector uses a mark-sweep algorithm. It provides incremental and **generational collection**](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected. I don't remember that from the paper. The conservative aspect gets more emphasis.